# Meanings of “bel et bien”

Tags: sens, locutions

I'm a little bit lost with the expression *bel et bien*. Usually it is translated as “indeed” or “in fact”, but there are times which there other better synonyms or expressions. I wish for a list with the translations of *bel et bien*, ordered by rate of appearance, so one could apply an algorithm when translating this expression.

Oh, and as an appendix, as I'm Brazilian I would like even more if I had translations in Portuguese. For now, I translate it as “de fato”, “claro” ou “é claro”.

Two sample phrases:

> Elle s'est **bel et bien** échappée.
>
> On l'a **bel et bien** obtenu son assentiment.

One of the difficulties appears in this phrase:

> Christian était *réellement* mécontent.

Which could be translated to:

> Christian was *indeed* unhappy.

But could we say?:

> Christian était *bel et bien* mécontent.

Comment: Thx for the welcoming, the portuguese translation would be a bonus, it's not required. But thanks for the collins dictionary, I didn't know that one, only _Littré_ and _Larousse_. My puzzle is trying to find an expression as fluid in portuguese, but there aren't that many resources as in english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bel et bien* is used to strenghten an assertion when there was an uncertainty about the fact, I believe "actually" is the closest English translation and perhaps *na realidade* in Portuguese.

> Elle s'est bel et bien échappée.

(We didn't think she will do it but) she actually escaped.

> On a bel et bien obtenu son assentiment.

(We thought we wouldn't but) we actually got their agreement.

In your example

> Christian était bel et bien mécontent.

(We thought he was not affected but) Christian was actually unhappy.

Comment: *Christian était bel et bien mécontent* = *Christian was actually unhappy* or *Christian was indeed unhappy*? Intuitively, I agree with your explanation but most dictionaries give _indeed_ or _well and truly_ as translations. _Na realidade_ seems like a good one, but speaking more naturally we would say _na verdade_. The question: is the premise of uncertainty absolutely necessary for _bel et bien_'s existence or is it a premise for the vast majority of cases?

Comment: If you search sentences where "bel et bien" appears, I'm sure you will notice there is always some form of uncertainty involved. Whether "indeed" or "na realidade" are the right translations are outside of my knowledge (and off topic here).